# Looking for software to interface GPS data with PC

Tags: gps, software-recommendations

I have GPS Unit from Garmin (GPS 18xPC).

I'm looking for software I can install on my PC that will allow me to interface with the data I collect on my GPS unit.

Any help will be great

Comment: @ Pradeep - please see my answer below RE: ArcGIS Explorer & DNR Garmin.  The map software is free, and although it doesn't do all that much "stand alone", you can add spatial data, satelite imagery, etc, etc .... as well, you can add GIS toolbox functionality via server feeds. Take a look!

Comment: Thanks for your answers,Will these software (GPSBabel,DNR Garmin) also give me the error and satellite information ?

Comment: All I can suggest is that you do some reading on the different packages that have been suggested Pradeep.  My experience has been that in good conditions, these hand-held units are +/- 2 metres on the x,y plane, but they can be out 10 metres or more in terms of elevation.  The only reason I know this is because we experimented in the field by comparing readings from our hand-held units versus readings from Geodetic Surveying equipment (by Trible - sub-centimetre accuracy). What degree of accuracy do you require?

Answer (score 8):

I've used [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/) to download data from GPS units onto my Ubuntu machine.

The producer of you GPS unit should also offer more specific tools for download.

Answer (score 5):

Don't know about your specific GPS, but we use [DNR Garmin](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/tools/arcview/extensions/DNRGarmin/DNRGarmin.html) with many different Garmin units.  You can download tracks, waypoints and routes and save them in a variety of file formats in both projected and unprojected coordinates.  (Edited out a duplicate link due to improper pasting)

EDIT  DNR Garmin is limited to Windows operating systems.  You might want to install QGIS if you want download and data viewing.  QGIS has the ability to communicate with GPS units through the Plugins | GPS menu option (don't know if all GPS's, but it works with our various Garmin units).  I think portions/all of GPS Babel are used by QGIS (@underdark, correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: @ Dan - there seems to be a second link to the same site right at the end of your post (indicated with a hyperlinked "#1".

Comment: no problem ... and yes it is  ;O)

Answer (score 1):

GPS Utils http://www.gpsu.co.uk/
works with my old Garmin, freeware up to a certain number of points. I paid the registration and have been happy for about 10 years and still rely on it. 
Will draw a map, output to huge range of formats.

Answer (score 0):

There's a free map software from ESRI called ArcGIS Explorer you can download [HERE](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer/index.html).  If you look to the left, there are tutorials available.  It's very simple to use.

Also, you can download DNR Garmin software [HERE](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/tools/arcview/extensions/DNRGarmin/DNRGarmin.html).  This allows you to get the data out of your GPS and into formats you can use in other software packages (including ArcGIS Explorer).  The site also gives a breakdown of the basics.  As well, I think ArcGIS Explorer "might" be capable of pulling the GPS data in right off your unit (not certain).  Do the tutorials ... very simple stuff and you'll be rolling in no time.

Have fun.